# React Native Image component source as ES6 import images

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, es6-modules

Is it possible to import images and use them in the `source` of an `<Image />` component?

I have a lot of places where I need to conditionally display an icon or another, based on state.
For example:

```
{isToggled ? (
  <Image
    resizeMode='contain'        
    source={require('../../assets/images/icon_chevron_up_B82BF9.png')}
    style={styles.toggleArrowImage}
  />
) : (
  <Image
    resizeMode='contain'
    source={require('../../assets/images/icon_chevron_down_B82BF9.png')}
    style={styles.toggleArrowImagew}
  />
)}
```

Or

```
const getToogleImageSource = () => {
  if (isToggled) {
    return require('../../assets/images/icon_chevron_up_B82BF9.png')
  }

  return require('../../assets/images/icon_chevron_down_B82BF9.png')
}

...
<Image
  resizeMode='contain'
  source={getToogleImageSource()}
  style={styles.toggleArrowImagew} 
/>
```

Looking at [React Native documentation on Image](http://reactnative.dev/docs/image), and search for this on StackOverflow , I always see solutions using `require` to get the source.

Hence my question about using ES6 import like this to reduce the number of lines of code (I also find it easier to read):

```
import chevronDown from ('../../assets/images/icon_chevron_down_B82BF9.png')
import chevronUp from ('../../assets/images/icon_chevron_up_B82BF9.png')

...

<Image
  resizeMode='contain'
  source={isToggled ? chevronUp : chevronDown}
  style={styles.toggleArrowImagew} 
/>
```

I tested it locally and it works fine, so I am wondering if this would cause a problem with a standalone app, due to the packager or something I ignore.

FYI, I have this in app.json:

```
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "assets/images/*"
],
```

Thanks for you help.

[EDIT]: I forgot to mention that I am using Expo

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following method when using images in the react-native app. Though this is still using the `required` keyword, I get the following advantages which you are also seeking.

- less number of code lines and ability to avoid repetitive `required` keyword for the same image in many places.
- Since it is a single point of import, an image throughout the app can be changed with a single line of code.
- very high readability

---

Here is the implementation with 3 simple steps.

1. In your `assets` directory define an index file `(index.tx)`. if you are using js `index.js`
2. do your all imports in the index file

   ```
   const images = {
       logo: require('./logo.png'),
       splash_image: require('./splash_image.png'),
       chevronUp: require('./chevronUp.png'),
       chevronUp: require('./chevronDown.png'),
   }

   export default images;
   ```
3. import the `index.tx` to your component and use as follows. you can use any images by using `image.filename`. and also no more `require` keyword in your components.

   ```
   import images from '../../../assets';
   ...

   <Image
     resizeMode='contain'
     source={isToggled ? images.chevronUp : images.chevronDown}
     style={styles.toggleArrowImagew} 
   />
   ```

hope this is what you are looking for :D

---

---

UPDATE after trying with `import`

just import the image as follows on the top fo the component.

```
import { ... , Image } from 'react-native';
import img_welcome from '../../images/welcome.png';

...

<Image source={img_welcome} />
```

this is perfectly working for me.

I don't have anything in the app.json except appnames

> The only difference I see from your code and my working code is having a  pair of round bracket `()` in the `import` statement

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot @omal-perera for this neat solution.
I am still curious about this `require` versus `es6 import`. Is the use of `require` mandatory?

Comment: I just checked the `import` keyword in my code and surprisingly it worked. I had never tried this before :D. I used the same normal code to import the image. I 'll edit the answer to add what I tried